# Powershell to change Registry Key

Tags: powershell, registry, registrykey

I have take ownership previously using this

```
$key  = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyKEY'
$acct = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Administrators")
$acl = Get-ACL $key
$acl.SetOwner($acct)
Set-ACL -Path $key -ACLObject $acl
```

But when I tried to change the Access to READ with this, it creates a new ACL while the original one is still there. How do I alter the original one and how do I do this for all of its subkeys as well ?

```
$acl = get-acl 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyKEY'
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule("Administrators","ReadKey","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
$acl | Set-Acl -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyKEY'
```

Comment: Do you meen `$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)` ?

Comment: I just want to change/update the existing one, but the script above creates a new one. And I have tested your suggestion, it does the same thing.